Is including weights in g-computation not the same as a plug-in doubly robust estimator?
In the R package vignette for WeightIt(), in the section "Modeling the Outcome", it explains that (assuming I'm reading correctly) that the purpose of applying g-computation after creating weights via a treatment model (e.g., IPTW) is not to arrive at a doubly robust estimator. I'm confused by this because in Robin and Hernan's Causal Inference What If: Fine Point 13.2, it explains that the doubly robust plug-in estimator is just that; applying g-computation on your data along with the weights generated by weighting arrives at a doubly robust estimate of the causal effect. (as a side question, does this apply to Matching as well?)
I'm assuming that this "contradiction" is likely not actually a contradiction and actually just a misunderstanding of the text on my part, but I'm having trouble figuring it out and would like some help.
Thank you!

From my read, I think the interpretation is that the model outcome is not necessary for analysis, but instead is there to reduce the variance in the estimates.

As the author of the WeightIt documentation, I'll explain my reasoning. I suppose it comes down to what is meant by a doubly-robust estimator. It is true that weighted g-computation, which is described in the WeightIt documentation as g-computation but using a weighted outcome model, is a doubly-robust estimator in the sense that if either the weights alone yield a consistent estimator or the outcome model yields a consistent estimator, the weighted g-computation estimator is consistent as well. (Note there are other definitions of doubly-robust, e.g., that refer to rates of convergence.)
The reason I am hesitant to advertise weighted g-computation as a doubly-robust estimator is that the outcome model is almost certainly wrong if it is fit as a generalized linear model. If you know the outcome model is wrong, then the estimator is not doubly-robust; you still only have one chance to get a model right, i.e., the model used to estimate the weights. That's why I place so much emphasis on getting the weights "right", i.e., by ensuring they are modeled flexibly so that balance is achieved in a broad and complete way, not just on the covariate means. If we can ensure our weighting model is "right", then we don't need to rely on the outcome model to give us another chance at being right; the purpose of the outcome model is simply to reduce the variance of the treatment effect estimate.
Note that this differs from how some other doubly-robust estimators are treated. AIPW and TMLE rely on a different formulation that allows them to achieve double-robustness in its true form; they do this by not requiring the outcome model to be weighted, and therefore it can be as flexible as possible and actually have a chance at being "right".
I don't know whether the plug-in estimator described in Fine Point 13.2 is more like weighted g-computation or AIPW in its flexibility. While it does not require fitting a weighted outcome model because the weights enter the model as a transformed covariate, it appears the double-robustness property might require that the outcome model use a canonical link, which is also true of weighted g-computation, and which significantly restricts the possibilities the model can have. Regardless, I believe this method has been studied and it tends to perform quite poorly empirically. AIPW and TMLE are far better studied and should be used as a first line of defense if one is primarily concerned with consistency of the estimator.
